# AWS ecosystem for emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, smtp

I am looking to transfer a domain name to AWS route53. But I need to confirm how can I then set up a mail domain and use that mail domain to send mails from my .Net application with? Any big picture directions as well as details are both welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to send emails to AWS. After transferring the domain name to AWS Route53, you can whitelist the domain in AWS SES.

You can use [AWS .NET SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) to send emails or use AWS SES SMTP credentials with a .NET SMTP library.

Comment: I already have a .Net client app. I just need to register (somehow) an email on that existing domain to use. Can SES set up all that? And do I need to get Workmail involved?

Comment: If its to send emails, SES is enough. If you need an inbox you will need Workmail or forward the mail to a different mail address.

Comment: A, perfect! That was the info I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses) to set it up after adding the MX record into AWS Route 53. If you intend to use AWS as an email client, I recommend you have a look at [AWS WorkMail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/).

Regarding big picture directions, AWS has a free 1-year tier for customers and developers to try out their vast range of services, and you certainly can make full use of it to test out and develop your application further before deciding the next development phase.

Assuming your application is not going to consume services that will exceed the free tier, in terms of costs, your setup will and should incur a US$0.50 charge for one hosted zone, as well as the prevalent pricing of your domain upon successful transfer to AWS. Do note to check with your current domain service provider to unlock and allow the transferring of domains. Else, you may have to re-purchase it from AWS.

Hope this helps.